# is there a stable version for UI Grid?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I only find the unstable version of UI Grid on the web. Is there a stable version already available or coming out any time soon?

Comment: unstable is ok for what we are doing at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, The stable version of `ui-grid` is not released yet.if you want stable version of grid,you can use `ng-grid`. `ng-grid` is older (version 2.x), `ui-grid` is newer (version 3.x) but not officially relased yet (currently in release candidate status). They're very similar.

Comment: yea, I am currently using UI Grid and integrated it in my project. looks good so far. But worried bcoz it's still going changes. I hope it won't effect any of my functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

A stable version of UI-Grid has been released (see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid and http://ui-grid.info/). The current latest version is 3.0.3.